# JSF commandbutton - styling

Tags: jsf

Is it possible to style JSF commandbutton tags to look like the following example:

http://www.bloggerswatch.com/internet/css-trick-submit-button-should-look-same-everywhere/

It works for the commandlink/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to do something similar using slightly different CSS that incorporates the images as CSS backgrounds rather than `<img>` tags:

**Markup**

```
<div class="buttons">
    <h:commandButton value="Button Text" styleClass="apply"/>
    <h:commandButton value="Button Text" styleClass="cross"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.buttons input {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 20px; /* 20px makes room for your background image */
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.buttons .apply {
    background: #eee url(path/to/apply.png) no-repeat 0 50%;
} 

.buttons .cross {
    background: #eee url(path/to/cross.png) no-repeat 0 50%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this almost duplicates the appearance of the example.  Is there a way to shift the image right a few pixels so it's not on the left edge?  I've tried adding a padding and margin attribute to the .apply style and the image doesn't shift over.

Comment: Absolutely.  You can play with the background position on the .apply and .cross classes.  Currently I've got it set as '0 50%' which means left edge, vertically centered.  If you changed it to '10px 50%' that would be 10px from the left, vertically centered.

Comment: Is there a way to turn off the button background changes during a mouseover? This app switches to a gradient background with no image.